# ExpandableListView child which contains a TableLayout and 3 Textview not firing click listener

Tags: android

In ExapndableListView, TableLayout is shown. In TableLayout, it contains 3 TextView in TableRow. In total there are 6 TableRow (just shown a sample in code). When I click on any items on TableRow, the click listener is not getting called. But if I click inbetween the TableRow, the click listener is firing.

I have tried android:focusable="false" with TextView, TableRow and TableLayout, but all in vain

Child Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/widget.margin.small">

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/rowKeyNumber">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abc"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.App.Primary.Dark.Medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.App.Accent.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/common.colon_separator" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/efg"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.App.Primary.Dark.Small"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout Design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/widget.margin.small"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Group Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget.padding.small">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.App.Primary.Light.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_expandable_list_close"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: can u show me your layout design ? with expandablelistview design

Comment: I have fixed that issue and it was not related to ExpandableListView